# Uso correcto de la palabra "asertivo/a"

Tags: uso-de-palabras, definiciones, significado, psicología

Hoy vi el siguiente comentario:

> Estoy de acuerdo con lo que dice la imagen, sin embargo no tiene nada que ver el texto con la foto, se llama populismo, hitler también lo hacía, no solo publiques por publicar, se asertiva.
>   Saludos.

Mas allá del contexto, me preguntaba a que se refería con `asertivo`, así que busqué el significado en RAE, y encontré esto:

> asertivo,
>
> De aserto.
>
> 1. adj. afirmativo.
> 2. adj. Psicol. Dicho de una persona: Que expresa su opinión de manera firme.
> 3. adj. Psicol. Propio de una persona asertiva..

Sin embargo, sentí que el significado que el comentario quiso transmitir diciendo `asertivo` es el siguiente:

> La asertividad es una habilidad social y comunicativa que consiste en conocer los propios derechos y defenderlos, respetando a los demás<sup>1</sup>

Así, las fuentes en las cuales se basa este artículo de wikipedia no me parecen confiables<sup>2,3</sup>, por lo cual tenía las siguientes dudas:

- Existe alguna razón para creer en estas definiciones de asertividad expuestas en Wikipedia y fuentes<sup>1,2,3</sup> y si así lo fuera, es correcta usarla aun si no esta definida así en la RAE?

---

1. [Asertividad - Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asertividad#cite_note-1)
2. [Recurso de Wikipedia 1](http://www.fundacioncadah.org/web/printPDF.php?idweb=1&account=j289eghfd7511986&contenido=tecnicas-para-conductas-asertivas)
3. [Recurso de Wikipedia 2](http://saberpsicologia.com/articulos/habilidades-sociales/que-es-la-asertividad/381)

Comment: Para mi la asertividad es la capacidad de comunicar algo de manera eficiente y oportuna de manera en la que tanto el emisor como el receptor han entendido el mensaje sin involucrar agentes externos no incluidos en la conversación, agentes como prejuicios, sentimientos emociones o sentimientos que no formaban parte del mensaje

Answer (score 1):

Las definiciones de `asertivo` de esos enlaces de Wikipedia no entran en conflicto con la definición de la RAE.

Puedes encontrar cómo se define el asertivismo en psicología en multitud de sitios de internet, y todos vienen a decir más o menos que es ese punto medio entre no expresar tus ideas con convicción y el estar tan convencido de que son correctas que intentas imponerlas a los demás.

El DRAE no es un manual de psicología y no va a expandir en si expones o no esas ideas de forma agresiva. Para mi la  clave de la definición del DRAE es `convicción`. Expresar tus ideas de forma *asertiva* es expresarlas con *convicción*. Entiendo que no tiene nada que ver con defenderlas de forma "tranquila" o "no agresiva" como un manual de psicología explicaría, si no más bien de forma "segura" (convencido de lo que dices).

Respondiendo a la pregunta: viendo varias páginas de psicología en internet todas definen el *asertivismo* de manera similar, por lo que deduzco que podemos dar por buenas la de los enlaces que aportas en la pregunta.

Sobre si es correcta usarla así incluso si no coincide con la definición del DRAE, ya puede depender de muchas otras cosas. No creo que alguien que exprese sus ideas de forma demasiado pasiva esté siendo asertivo (porque denota falta de convicción). Si la persona es demasiado agresiva, no creo que necesariamente sea no asertiva.

Comment: Hola Diego, gracias por tomarte el tiempo de responder. Sobre el tema, yo creo que las definiciones **si** entran en conflicto. Lo digo por la el uso de la palabra `firme` que como una de sus acepciones: `7. adv. Con firmeza, con valor, con violencia.`. Teniendo en cuenta esto, una persona asertiva, tal vez no es la persona que defiende violentamente su postura pero al `firme` estar relacionada con violencia, creo yo, difiere mucho de un punto medio.

Comment: La definiciones del DRAE no tienen precisión matemática. Yo me quedaría con la 1a acepción de "firme" (Estable, fuerte, que no se mueve ni vacila) o la 2a antes que con la 7a. En misma 7a acepción tenemos "valor" y "violencia", que no son sinónimos. No todo lo que se hace con valor se hace con violencia o viceversa. No hay una "conjunción" de esos adjetivos. Así que aunque puedas encadenar en las definiciones Asertivo >> Firme >> Violencia, la **interpretación** al leer la definición de "asertivo" no debería ser "con valor **+** violencia", sino "Seguro. Sin vacilar". Le buscas 3 pies al gato.

Comment: No trato de buscar una sinrazón, sino llegar al fondo que plantea esta pregunta. Sobre la relación > asertivo >> firme >> violento, estoy de acuerdo contigo que no es la correcta **interpretación**. Sin embargo, no estoy convencido que defender una posición de manera firme se equipara con defender una posición con una conducta intermedia entre la agresividad y pasividad