# What is the Spanish word for "emotional strength"?

Tags: vocabulario, solicitud-de-término, psicología

I know the word **fuerza**. It means strength. But which strength is meant by it, physical or emotional? I am looking for a Spanish word which refers to emotional strength.

Comment: [Fortaleza](https://dle.rae.es/fortaleza)?

Comment: Probably "fuerza emocional" would be the best "one size fits all" translation. There is a wide set of words that could be used for "emotional strength" depending on the context of how it is used. [Resiliencia](https://dle.rae.es/resiliencia?m=form) is the one that comes to mind first, but there could be a lot of synonyms. Please, provide some context and a example to clarify.

Comment: I'd say "fortaleza espiritual" or "fortaleza interior"

Comment: Aprovecho para recuperar una pregunta anterior, levemente relacionada, que no recibió demasiada atención: [Uso correcto de la palabra “asertivo/a”](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/26950/5481)

Comment: I would say ' de carácter fuerte'

Comment: "Fuerza emocional" sounds OK, "fortaleza emocional" sounds better if you mean more like "fortitude, resilience, ability to cope".

Comment: @pablodf76 yeah fortaleza emocional is what I am looking for. But is there any single word term for that as well?

Comment: _Temple_ has a close meaning: "Fortaleza enérgica y valentía serena para afrontar las dificultades y los riesgos." ("Energetic strength and serene courage to face difficulties and risks")

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A good translation is [**entereza**](https://dle.rae.es/entereza). The dictionary of the RAE defines it as:

> 3. f. Valor, fortaleza de ánimo.

that is, emotional strength.

Answer (score 0):

The word **[fuerza](https://dle.rae.es/?w=fuerza)** can indeed be used for both physical and emotional strength. Moreover, it also means force. To illustrate it some examples are, respectively:

- *Ella tiene mucha más fuerza en los brazos desde que va al gimnasio*.
- *Ante esta situación debemos tener fuerza y permanecer unidos*.
- *La segunda ley de Newton afirma que la fuerza es igual a la masa por la aceleración*.

The first two acceptions correspond to the adjective **fuerte**:

- *Ella se ha puesto fuerte*.
- *Tenemos que ser fuertes*.

Comment: Tu respuesta tendría más **fuerza** si la respaldaras con una referencia a la segunda acepción que muestra el DLE [aquí](https://dle.rae.es/?w=fuerza).

Answer (score 0):

The words you are looking for is: "**Fortaleza emocional**".

Ejemplo: *Gracias a su fortaleza emocional, Mayte logró superar la crisis.*

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the type of the text you are translating.

*Fortaleza emocional* would maybe fit better as '*fuerza*' has more connotation of physical power - derived from 'fuerte'(strong), but depends on the translator and on the context for sure.

If you want to put more emphasis on the strength -go for '*fuerza*'